# How can I download the openlayers.js with controls' icons?

Tags: icons, controls, openlayers

I would need the openlayers use from my server, the openlayers.js is downloadable as well. But the control menu's icons points to an indirect reference... I can download these images, but how can I overwrite the .js to use these downloaded icons? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code where you experience the problem?

Comment: You don't need code... I want to download the openlayers.js some way. Here is the download page: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/HowToDownload
But I need to change it somehow, than it can use my images from a local reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about *local reference* - do you mean your own custom icons or just the default OpenLayers icons hosted at your server?

Comment: The latter, I hosted them on my server.

Answer (score 0):

For me, that img folder has to sit in the same directory as the openlayers.js file. So, if I have root/js/OpenLayers.js, then those files need to be in root/js/img/...